# Symfony Automatic Service Loading fails with "Class does not exist"

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am trying the new automatic service loading using Symfony's Dependency Injection component (stand-alone, not within a Symfony app), version `v3.3.13`.

If I manually define a service, the class is loaded correctly:

```
# services.yml
myasset:
    class: Mysite\Asset\Asset

# in a PHP file
$container->get('myasset'); # works
```

If I set up automatic loading, it fails with the error message:
*ReflectionException: Class does not exist in /var/www/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 1070*

```
# services.yml
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    Bloggi\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        public: true

# in a PHP file
$container->get(Mysite\Asset\Asset::class);
```

The reason it fails is because the classes are found and service definitions created, but the `class` attribute on the definition is `null` for the automatically loaded services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My DIC configuration looked like:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load(__DIR__ . '/../config/services.yml');
```

The missing line was `$container->compile();`

**The working definition**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load(__DIR__ . '/../config/services.yml');
$container->compile();
```

Comment: Accept your own answer please. :)

Comment: You asked and answered your question the same minute..  Very suspicious

Comment: @Akintunde Yes - I ticked the "Answer your own Question" box. Having written the question and found the answer as I finished, would've been a waste not to publish

Comment: @Akintunde Before you throw around accusations, do please define 'Very suspicious' of what.

Comment: Are you using the regular Symfony framework?  Normally you don't need the compile line.

Comment: Nothing suspicious, generally you continue to work on your problem after having published your question. That's what every so users should do.

Comment: @Cerad No, just the component. In the tests I included composer's autoload.php at the top, then the definition of the ContainerBuilder, and then a test `$container->get()` call to check it resolved correctly.